# Query for N most recent records by ChangeDate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I have a table with columns:

```
ID(Int) 
Value(Int) 
ChangeDate(DateTime)
```

After updating the table I want to select N (lets say 1000) records in which value for 
`ChangeDate` is highest (meaning newest dates). What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: What have you already tried, from your description sounds like you need something like `SELECT TOP 100...` or possibly use the `LIMIT` clause, alternatively you might have reasoning to get the `ROW_NUMBER` and limit using the clause. You will need to add more detail to get the answer you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1000
    *
FROM 
    TABLE_NAME
ORDER BY 
    ChangeDate DESC
```

Comment: This one is ok. Actually I made a stupid mistake by putting ASC in ORDER BY. THX!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @N int

SET @N = 1000

SELECT TOP (@N) * FROM [YourTable] ORDER BY ChangeDate DESC
```